# meteor-roles package, adding roles

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

```
Meteor.publish(null, function (){

var users = [ Meteor.users.find({})];
email="Osoba5@qwe.qwe";
if(users == email ){
    users = Meteor.this.userId;
    Roles.createRole('admin');
    Roles.setUserRoles(users, 'admin');
}else{
    users = Meteor.this.userId;
    Roles.createRole(['']);
    Roles.setUserRoles(users,['']);
}
return Meteor.users.find({});
});}
```

The goal is when creating user there are two user acc one should have admin and the other is normal user without role. But when I sign in with acc who should get admin role I can't do the things I specified for acc with admin role. I'm missing something and I can't figure what, Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mistakes in this code:

Firstly, you are setting users to be equal to an array and then checking if it is equal to a string. This will always return false.

Secondly, `Meteor.this.userId`, should be `this.userId` instead.

Thirdly, change this line:

```
var users = [ Meteor.users.find({})];
```

to either:

```
var users = Meteor.users.find({}); // users is a cursor
```

or:

```
var users = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch(); // users is an array
```

Comment: thank you for the help in correcting the code. I made it work